# Which PUBG vehicle can go the farthest without running out of gas?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Which vehicle in PUBG can go the farthest on a tank of gas? (I'm assuming that on every spawn, each vehicle type is spawned with the same amount of gas)

Comment: From what I remember, vehicles have a random amount of gas when they spawn. Don't think I have ever seen less than half a tank in an untouched vehicle though. Beyond that are you asking about Land or Sea Vehicles? or Both?

Comment: @Malco If someone has information on it, then both. But my main concern is land vehicles.

Comment: buggy is the most fuel efficient vehicle in pubg after the motorcycle without the side cart.

Answer (score -1):

They are all about the same. I experimented with different vehicles awhile back and found only small differences in distance traveled.